# My kubernetes cluster IP address changed and now kubectl will no longer connect

Tags: kubernetes

- Running under Ubuntu I used `kubeadm init` to setup my cluster (master node) and copied over the `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config` and all was well when using `kubectl`.
- However after a reboot my master node has had an IP address change which is not the same as what is in `$HOME/.kube/config` so now I can no longer connect `kubectl`

So how do I regenerate the admin.conf now that I have a new IP address? Running `kubeadm init` will just kill everything which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not want to use `kubeadm reset`. That will reset everything and you would have to start configuring your cluster again.

Well, in your scenario, please have a look on the steps below:

1. `nano /etc/hosts` (update your new IP against `YOUR_HOSTNAME`)
2. `nano /etc/kubernetes/config` (configuration settings related to your cluster) here in this file look for the following params and update accordingly

   `KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://YOUR_HOSTNAME:8080"`

   `KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://YOUR_HOSTNAME:2379" #2379 is default port`
3. `nano /etc/etcd/etcd.conf` (`conf` related to `etcd`)

   `KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://YOUR_HOSTNAME/WHERE_EVER_ETCD_HOSTED:2379"`

   `2379` is default port for `etcd`. and you can have multiple `etcd` servers defined here comma separated
4. Restart `kubelet`, `apiserver`, `etcd` services.

It is good to use `hostname` instead of `IP` to avoid such scenarios.

Hope it helps!

Comment: you should also update hostname conf on minions(worker nodes) as well like as follows:

**nano /etc/kubernetes/config**
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://hostname:8080"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://hostname:2379"

**now edit kubelet conf**
nano /etc/kubernetes/kubelet
KUBELET_HOSTNAME="--hostname-override=hostname-minion"
KUBELET_API_SERVER="--api-servers=http://hostname:8080"

Comment: For my side, there is no file /etc/kubernetes/config ?  I have below files in kubernetes folder: admin.conf, kubelet.conf, controller-manager.conf, pki folder, manifests folder, scheduler.conf. And I am not successful when do with your way. Do you need to recreate key files ?

Answer (score 10):

I found this solution on the internet and it works for me:

```
    systemctl stop kubelet docker
    cd /etc/
    mv kubernetes kubernetes-backup
    mv /var/lib/kubelet /var/lib/kubelet-backup
    mkdir -p kubernetes
    cp -r kubernetes-backup/pki kubernetes
    rm kubernetes/pki/{apiserver.*,etcd/peer.*}
    systemctl start docker
    kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd
    #Run "kubeadm reset" on all nodes if was this error "error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-kubelet.conf]: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists
        [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists"
    cp kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
    kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
    kubectl delete node $(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[(@.status.conditions[0].status=="Unknown")].metadata.name}')
    kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

After These, Join your Slaves to Master.
Reference: https://medium.com/@juniarto.samsudin/ip-address-changes-in-kubernetes-master-node-11527b867e88

Comment: I think this is the easiest one among all the answers.

Answer (score 6):

The following command can be used to regenerate **admin.conf**

```
kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin --apiserver-advertise-address <new_ip>
```

However, if you use an IP instead of a hostname, your API-server certificate will be invalid. So, either regenerate your certs ( *kubeadm alpha phase certs renew apiserver* ), use hostnames instead of IPs or add the **insecure** *--insecure-skip-tls-verify* flag when using kubectl

Comment: Error: unknown flag: --apiserver-advertise-address

Answer (score 0):

Please find K8S cluster settings, where master and worker IP has changed.

- Edit `/etc/hosts` file with new host IP of master and worker nodes
- Then reset cluster:

For 1.23 version: `sudo kubeadm reset`

For 1.26/27 version: `sudo kubeadm reset --cri-socket unix:///run/cri-dockerd.sock`

- Reinitialize the cluster

For version 1.23: `sudo kubeadm init`

For version 1.26: `sudo kubeadm init --cri-socket unix:///run/cri-dockerd.sock`
This command will generate key to join worker.

- The run the following 3 commands in master node:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -f /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

- Run cluster join command in worker node:

For version 1.23: generated key in master node
For version 1.26: generated key in master node and --cri-socket unix:///run/cri-dockerd.sock